# Aggregation on complex objects

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection with documents like the following:

```
{
  "towers": [
    {
      "name": "foo",
      "towers": [
        {
          "name": "A",
          "buildType": "Apartament"
        },
        {
          "name": "B",
          "buildType": "Apartament"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "xpto",
      "towers": [
        {
          "name": "C",
          "buildType": "House"
        },
        {
          "name": "D",
          "buildType": "Office"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

All I need to know is what are all the possible values for "buildType", like:

- Apartment
- House
- Office

It's a complex object and the data to aggregate is deep inside it. Is there any way to achieve the results I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the two nested array that is "towers" and "towers.towers" and then use [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) with "towers.towers.buildType" field to get the distinct values

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$towers" },
  { "$unwind": "$towers.towers" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$towers.towers.buildType"
  }}
])
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "_id": "Office"
  },
  {
    "_id": "House"
  },
  {
    "_id": "Apartament"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $unwind: {
                path: "$towers",

            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $unwind: {
                path: "$towers.towers",
            }
        },

        // Stage 3
        {
            $group: {
                _id: '$_id',
                buildType: {
                    $addToSet: '$towers.towers.buildType'
                }
            }
        },

    ]



);
```